# MPC output problem on Headphone output

Tags: pi-2, audio, pulseaudio, raspberry-pi-os-buster, mpd

I have a misconfiguration of my MPD daemon on Raspbian Buster with Raspberry PI 2B.

Alsa is configured as follows:

```
pi@Wecker:~ $ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: b1 [bcm2835 HDMI 1], device 0: bcm2835 HDMI 1 [bcm2835 HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 4/4
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
card 1: Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones], device 0: bcm2835 Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones]
  Subdevices: 4/4
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
pi@Wecker:~ $ aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default
output
sysdefault:CARD=b1
    bcm2835 HDMI 1, bcm2835 HDMI 1
    Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=b1,DEV=0
    bcm2835 HDMI 1, bcm2835 HDMI 1
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=b1,DEV=0
    bcm2835 HDMI 1, bcm2835 HDMI 1
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=b1,DEV=0
    bcm2835 HDMI 1, bcm2835 HDMI 1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=b1,DEV=0
    bcm2835 HDMI 1, bcm2835 HDMI 1
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=Headphones
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Hardware device with all software conversions
pi@Wecker:~ $
```

`aplay sound.wav` works, I can hear the sound on the headphone output.

MPD is configured and MPC is playing:

```
pi@Wecker:~ $ mpc play
SWR3 MP3 128: SOUNDS mit Bernd Lechler
[playing] #1/1   0:00/0:00 (0%)
volume: n/a   repeat: off   random: off   single: off   consume: off
pi@Wecker:~ $ mpc
SWR3 MP3 128: Crying in the club / Camila Cabello
[playing] #1/1   0:09/0:00 (0%)
volume: n/a   repeat: off   random: off   single: off   consume: off
```

But there is nothing on the headphone output. It's strange that the volume ist not available.

The relevant section in the mpd.conf:

```
# An example of an ALSA output:
#
audio_output {
        type            "alsa"
        name            "My ALSA Device"
#       type            "pulse"
#       name            "pulse audio"
#       device          "hw:0,0"        # optional
#       mixer_type      "hardware"      # optional
#       mixer_device    "default"       # optional
#       mixer_control   "Headphone"     # von Michael
#       mixer_control   "PCM"           # optional
#       mixer_index     "0"             # optional
}
```

.asoundrc:

```
pcm.!default {
  type asym
  playback.pcm {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "output"
  }
  capture.pcm {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "input"
  }
}

pcm.output {
  type hw
  card 1
}

ctl.!default {
  type hw
  card 1
}
```

aplay is functional with the current configuration, but MPC not.

If I delete .asoundrc for the root user, mpc plays on HDMI. In this case the headphone output is missing for the root user. Only with the .asoundrc above for the root user, aplay plays on the headphone, but mpc not.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by myself:
in mpd.conf I activated the following line:

```
#       device          "hw:1,0"        # optional
```

The **1** after **hw:** was the important part.